# verify loading indicator shows with cypress

Tags: cypress

I have the following spec:

```
context('Contact update', () => {
  it.only('Can update contact', () => {
    const address = 'new address 123'
    const cardId = 'c2card-38AF429999C93B5DC844D86381734E62'
    cy.viewport('macbook-15')
    cy.authVisit('/contact/list')
    cy.getByTestId('open-doc-Aaron Dolney-0').click()
    cy.get('[name="physicaladdress"').type(`{selectall}{backspace}${address}`)
    cy.getByTestId(cardId, 'save-button').click()
    cy.getByTestId(cardId, 'loading')
    cy.get('[name="physicaladdress"').should('have.value', address)
  })
})
```

`getByTestId` is a command I wrote to reduce some boilerplate:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getByTestId', (...ids) => {
  const id = ids.map(id => `[data-testid="${id}"]`).join(' ')
  return cy.get(id)
})
```

When I run this with anything other than `cypress open`, it fails on getting the loading indicator. I'm thinking my test endpoint is responding too fast and toggling the loading indicator too quickly.

Is there a better, more consistent, way to verify the loading indicator shows?

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with your Cypress code, so the error here will have something to do with how Cypress is interacting with your specific application setup. When you say it fails, what do you mean? Does the element search time out, and if so, does it seem to do so before the indicator shows, or does it seem to time out while the indicator is still there / after it has disappeared?

Comment: Yes the search for the loading element times out. I _believe_ it's because it happens too quickly. When the test runs in `headed` mode, I can actually see the loading indicator flash for a second but cypress doesn't pick that up. If I add an intentional 20ms delay to my api, it works which is the work around I'm using now. I don't have to add the 20ms delay when I run the test from the cypress ui. Have to assume that it's an Electron Chromium vs Chrome issue.

Comment: Yeah, if your loading meter goes away faster than Cypress can move from the click command to the assertion on the loading meter then delaying in your API [probably isn't a bad solution](). Another thing you could do is to use a `.then()` to trigger the submit button and use a `setTimeout()` to delay the pressing of the submit button. That way, Cypress would run the code that sets up the timeout and then start waiting for the loading indicator before it showed. It's possible this could still be flaky though if the loading indicator doesn't stay around for long enough.

Comment: This starts getting into antipattern territory as described by the docs. You will have a harder time if you're expecting something to exist that is only there for a very short amount of time. [This doc page](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#Element-Existence) is related, even though it doesn't quite address the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this as well since I wanted to make sure the loading indicator was showing so I had to get a bit crafty. I found that `cy.route()` has an `onRequest` option and that ended up being just what I needed.

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Options

```
    cy.server();
    // Verify that the loading indicator is shown before the request finishes
    cy.route({
      url: url_of_request_that_triggers_loading,
      onRequest: () => {
        cy.getByTestId(cardId, 'loading');
      },
    });
```

With this implementation we run the loading expectation before the request finishes and before the loading indicator disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I found quite a reliable although bit complicated solution to that. I uses jQuery Deferred (bundled with cypress) along with internal cypress state (via aliases).

For extensive testing of intermediate states it works great.

```js
/**
 * Workaround for delegating {@link Cypress.Chainable['intercept']} - internal Method type is
 * not exported and thus delegating it is difficult. It's also difficult to extract it from
 * the function type because of overloads. If any more methods are needed, feel free
 * to add them here
 */
type Method = 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PATCH' | 'DELETE';

// extend this type if you need more flexibility
export interface ResponseStub {
  status: number;
  response: unknown;
}

/**
 * Deferred needs to be wrapped in an object because wrap() acts differently on promise-like args
 */
type InertDeferred = { deferred: Deferred<Partial<ResponseStub> | undefined> };

const deferredAlias = (aliasId: string): string => `${aliasId}Deferred`;
const deferredAliasSelector = (aliasId: string): string => `@${deferredAlias(aliasId)}`;

export const deferredRequestCommand = (
  method: Method,
  url: string,
  aliasId: string,
  fixture: string,
): void => {
  const deferred: InertDeferred['deferred'] = Cypress.$.Deferred();
  cy.wrap({ deferred }).as(deferredAlias(aliasId));

  cy.fixture(fixture).then((data) => {
    cy.intercept(method, url, (req) => {
      deferred
        .then((stub) => {
          req.reply(stub?.status || 200, stub?.response || data);
        });
      return deferred.promise();
    });
  });
};

export const resolveDeferredRequestCommand = (
  aliasId: string,
  stub: Partial<ResponseStub> = undefined,
): void => {
  cy.get<InertDeferred>(deferredAliasSelector(aliasId))
    .invoke('deferred.resolve', stub);
};
```