# How to check for transition elements (e.g. spinners) immediately after a n/w request is initiated using Cypress?

Tags: mocha.js, chai, e2e-testing, cypress

I know Cypress allows to check the request/response and assert them. But immediately after a request is initiated, how do I check for transition elements? For instance, asserting for a spinner on the page after a n/w req is made. Since requests can also be 302 redirects, Cypress will wait for the page to load for me to execute any further assertions - which is not helpful since the transition element is not on this page.

Comment: see if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737844/verify-loading-indicator-shows-with-cypress